# Sorting list of dictionaries with primary key from list of keywords and alphabetical order as secondary key

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries and I want them to be sorted according to a list of keywords as primary key and otherwise equal entries alphabetically.

Currently I sort first alphabetically and then according to the provided keywords which produces the desired result because of the stable sorting algorithm being used. However, I think this can be done in one step, but I don't know why. Can anyone help?

Secondly I would want to be able to use keywords instead of exact matches for the keyword sorting part. How can I do this?

Here's my code so far:

```
# Define the keywords I want to see first
preferred_projects = ['project one', 'project two', 'project three']

# example data
AllMyProjectsFromaDatasource = [{ 'name': 'project two', 'id': 5, 'otherkey': 'othervalue'},
                                { 'name': 'project three', 'id': 1, 'otherkey': 'othervalue'},
                                { 'name': 'project one', 'id': 3, 'otherkey': 'othervalue'},
                                { 'name': 'abc project', 'id': 6, 'otherkey': 'othervalue'},
                                { 'name': 'one project', 'id': 9, 'otherkey': 'othervalue'}
                               ]    


def sort_by_preferred(key):
    """Sort lists out by prefered name."""
     sortkey = key['name']
     return preferred.index(sortkey) if sortkey in preferred else len(preferred)

# First sort alphabetical    
AllProjects = sorted(AllMyProjectsFromaDatasource,
                     key=lambda k: k['name'])

# Then sort by keyword
preferred = preferred_projects
AllProjects.sort(key=sort_by_preferred)
```

So actually I want to define my "sorting filter" just like this:

```
preferred_projects = ['one', 'two', 'three']
```

And have the list sorted like this:

```
[{ 'name': 'one project', 'id': 9, 'otherkey': 'othervalue'}
 { 'name': 'project one', 'id': 3, 'otherkey': 'othervalue'},
 { 'name': 'project two', 'id': 5, 'otherkey': 'othervalue'},
 { 'name': 'project three', 'id': 1, 'otherkey': 'othervalue'},
 { 'name': 'abc project', 'id': 6, 'otherkey': 'othervalue'},]
```

Comment: Can you please show an example of your dictionary?

Comment: from the other solutions, I still miss my second question: I want to prefer just "one", so no matter what project that contains in it's name "one", will be in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`in`-operator](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#in) to find out whether a substring is contained in another string).

> For the Unicode and string types, `x in y` is true if and only if `x` is a substring of `y`. An equivalent test is `y.find(x) != -1`. [...] Empty strings are always considered to be a substring of any other string, so `"" in "abc"` will return `True`.

You can use this to implement your keyword sorting key.

You'd use the approach given in the other answer (pass a tuple as key) to implement the alphabetical sorting as a secondary key.

Here's an example:

```
import pprint

# Define the keywords I want to see first
preferred_projects = ['one', 'two', 'three']

# example data
AllMyProjectsFromaDatasource = [{ 'name': 'project two', 'id': 5, 'otherkey': 'othervalue'},
                                { 'name': 'project three', 'id': 1, 'otherkey': 'othervalue'},
                                { 'name': 'project one', 'id': 3, 'otherkey': 'othervalue'},
                                { 'name': 'abc project', 'id': 6, 'otherkey': 'othervalue'},
                                { 'name': 'one project', 'id': 9, 'otherkey': 'othervalue'}
                               ]    

def keyfunc(x):
    # keyword primary key
    # (add index to list comprehension when keyword is in name)
    preferred_key = [float(idx) 
                     for idx, i in enumerate(preferred_projects)
                     if i in x['name']]
    # found at least one match in preferred keywords, use first if any, else infinity
    keyword_sortkey = preferred_key[0] if preferred_key else float('inf')
    # return tuple to sort according to primary and secondary key
    return keyword_sortkey, x['name']

AllMyProjectsFromaDatasource.sort(key=keyfunc)

pprint.pprint(AllMyProjectsFromaDatasource)
```

The output is:

```
[{'id': 9, 'name': 'one project', 'otherkey': 'othervalue'},
 {'id': 3, 'name': 'project one', 'otherkey': 'othervalue'},
 {'id': 5, 'name': 'project two', 'otherkey': 'othervalue'},
 {'id': 1, 'name': 'project three', 'otherkey': 'othervalue'},
 {'id': 6, 'name': 'abc project', 'otherkey': 'othervalue'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a suitable tuple as your sort key. The first part is the index into your `preferred_projects` with a default value being the greatest index. The second part would be the name to allow an alphabetical sort:

```
preferred_projects = ['project one', 'project two', 'project three']

def sort_by(entry):
    name = entry['name']

    try:
        index = preferred_projects.index(name)
    except ValueError:
        index = len(preferred_projects)

    return (index, name)

AllMyProjectsFromaDatasource = [
    { 'name': 'project two', 'id': 5, 'otherkey': 'othervalue'},
    { 'name': 'project three', 'id': 1, 'otherkey': 'othervalue'},
    { 'name': 'project one', 'id': 3, 'otherkey': 'othervalue'},
    { 'name': 'abc project', 'id': 6, 'otherkey': 'othervalue'},
    { 'name': 'one project', 'id': 9, 'otherkey': 'othervalue'}]    

AllProjects = sorted(AllMyProjectsFromaDatasource, key=sort_by)

for p in AllProjects:
    print p
```

Giving you the following output:

```
{'otherkey': 'othervalue', 'name': 'project one', 'id': 3}
{'otherkey': 'othervalue', 'name': 'project two', 'id': 5}
{'otherkey': 'othervalue', 'name': 'project three', 'id': 1}
{'otherkey': 'othervalue', 'name': 'abc project', 'id': 6}
{'otherkey': 'othervalue', 'name': 'one project', 'id': 9}
```